# Python. wheezy.captcha. ImportError: No module named image

Tags: python, import, shared-libraries

I'm trying running [the sample](https://bitbucket.org/akorn/wheezy.captcha/src/3fe0eabe026f86e3759f8012836aff897d375eb2/demos/sample.py?at=default), but the error message keeps showing up. `wheezy.captcha` is installed. Here is the output about my Python and wheezy.captcha.

```
maksim-dmitriev@N550JV:~/Downloads$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
maksim-dmitriev@N550JV:~/Downloads$ ls  -la /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wheezy.captcha-0.1.29-py2.7.egg/
total 16
drwxr-sr-x  4 root staff 4096 May 11 14:28 .
drwxrwsr-x 20 root staff 4096 May 11 17:58 ..
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4096 May 11 14:28 EGG-INFO
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff 4096 May 11 14:28 wheezy
maksim-dmitriev@N550JV:~/Downloads$ python sample.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    from wheezy.captcha.image import captcha
ImportError: No module named image
maksim-dmitriev@N550JV:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: Try to find out the version of the library

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini, wheezy.captcha-**0.1.29**-py2.7.egg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed `wheezy` as root. When I ran sample.py using sudo, it worked